# IdentityServer4 QuickStart2_ResourceOwnerPasswords System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to run the [QuickStart2_ResourceOwnerPasswords](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/2_ResourceOwnerPasswords) sample. I could view the `http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration` without issues. However when I run the `Client.dll` from the console it gives me following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Note: I am running the `QuickStartIdentityServer` as start up project (this runs the Identity Server implementation in the background with command window showing logs). I am currently running the `Client.dll` from a separate window using the command:

```
dotnet Client.dll
```

Not sure if this is the correct way of testing it...

Comment: Your identity server must be in running state. Then the client will be able to call it.

Comment: If the Identity Server is not running how could I view the openid-configuration url? Moreover I could see that command window display that server is running when the error occurred...